# Extract the first word after a given string in a variable

Tags: javascript

Given a sentence `the description is about fast cars`. And a string `str = description is`, How can i get the word "about"?

I tried some look behind regex but could not come up with a elegant way. Any suggestion other then use the indexOf few times along with split an splice? thx

```
    let re = new RegExp('(?<=' + str + ').*');
    let result = mySentence.match(re)[0].split(' ')[0];
```

**edit**
I forgot to add that `str` match should be case insensitive.

Comment: This might help: https://regex101.com/r/a7MUhE/1

Comment: You might like `str.substring(str.indexOf(s) + s.length, str.indexOf(' ', str.indexOf(s) + s.length + 1)).trim()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for a lookahead.

```js
let s = "the description is about fast cars"
let f = "description is";

let r = new RegExp(f + "\\s(\\w+)");
console.log(s.match(r)[1]);
```

Comment: This solution fails if there is a number in the sentence. Like `s = "the distance is 3.5 meters"` and `f = 'distance is'`, I tried fow ways to change the `\\w+` to `\\b.*?\\b` for no avail. Any suggestions? thx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var sentence = "the description is about fast cars";
var word = "description is";

function getFirstAfterSplitSentence(sentence, word) {
  return sentence.split(word)[1].split(" ")[1];
}

console.log(getFirstAfterSplitSentence(sentence, "is"));
```

Answer (score 0):

A general approach would be:

```js
const orig = 'the description is about fast cars';
const str = 'description is';

const result = orig.split(str).pop().trim().split(' ').shift();
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```